# What approach should I take towards converting ascii chars to other chars in c++

Tags: c++

Well currently I am re creating my own version of enigma as a little project but if you understand how the enigma machine works it has rotors which connect a character to a completely different character for example A might be connected to F or U may be connected to C and this is done three times. Currently I am getting the char for the rotor by using this function:

```
char getRotorOne(char i) {
if(i == 'a') {
    return 'g';
}if(i == 'b') {
    return 'A';
}if(i == 'c') {
    return 'o';
}
```

The main problem with this is it takes a long time to write and it seems inefficient and I think there must be a better way. The other problem with this is on the original enigma machine there were only the 26 letters of the alphabet on this there are the 94 tapeable characters of ascii (32-126) is there any other simpler way that this can be done? If you think this question is unclear or you don't understand please tell me instead of just flagging my post, then you can help me improve my question.

Comment: Declare an char array that holds the character for each index? `char array[126] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', ... }; return array['a'];`

Comment: either a `map` or `array` mapping

Comment: yes but how can i get it to return a result? it needs to have an input of a for example then give me back g

Comment: Look at @Cyclone 's comment a bit better. Literally `return array[inputValue];`

Comment: @user4581301 He only has one array is he suggesting for each rotor i have two arrays and i get the index of the same char in the second array?

Comment: Oh i only just saw your second comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use tables! Conveniently, C string literals are arrays of characters. So you can do this:

```
//                           abc
const char* lower_mapping = "gAo";

//                           ABC
const char* upper_mapping = "xyz";

char getRotorOne(char i) {
    if (i >= 'a' && i <= 'z') return lower_mapping[i - 'a'];
    if (i >= 'A' && i <= 'Z') return upper_mapping[i - 'A'];
    assert(false && "Unknown character cannot be mapped!");
}
```

Since `char`s are really just small integers, and ASCII guarantees contiguous ranges for `a-z` and `A-Z` (and `0-9`) you can subtract from a given character the first one in its range (so, `'a'` or `'A'`) to get an index into that range. That index can then be used to look up the corresponding character via a table, which in this case is just a simple hardcoded string literal.

Answer (score 2):

This is an improvement on Cameron's answer. You should use a simple char array for each *rotor*, but as you said you want to process ASCII characters in the range 32-126, you should build each mapping as an array of 95 characters:

```
char rotor1[95] ="aXc;-0..."; // the 95 non control ascii characters in arbitrary order
```

Then you write your rotor function that way:

```
char getRotorOne(char i) {
    if ((i < 32) || (i > 126)) return i; // do not change non processed characters
    return rotor1[i - 32];  // i - 32 is in range 0 - 94: rotor1[i - 32] is defined
}
```

Comment: I would use character literals instead of integer constants to improve readability, they're the same to the compiler

Comment: @NicholasMertin: I generaly do that, but here OP explicitely asked to process ASCII characters in the range 32 (space) to 126 (`~`) which gives exactly 95 characters. In that case, I find the numeric values more readable that the character litterals. Do you really think that `if ((i < 32) || (i > 126))` is less clear than `if ((i < ' ') || (i > '~'))`. Personnaly, I do have known for years that ascii code for space is 0x20 or 32, but I had to look to a table to remember that tilda has code 126.